# Convert AVAudioPCMBuffer to NSData and back

Tags: swift, ios8, nsdata, avaudiopcmbuffer

How to convert `AVAudioPCMBuffer` to `NSData`? If it should be done as

```
let data = NSData(bytes: buffer.floatChannelData, length: bufferLength)
```

then how to calculate `bufferLength`?

And how to convert `NSData` to `AVAudioPCMBuffer`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Buffer length is frameCapacity * bytesPerFrame. Here are functions that can do conversion between NSData and AVAudioPCMBuffer.

```swift
extension AVAudioPCMBuffer {
    func data() -> Data {
        let channelCount = 1  // given PCMBuffer channel count is 1
        let channels = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: self.floatChannelData, count: channelCount)
        let ch0Data = NSData(bytes: channels[0], length:Int(self.frameCapacity * self.format.streamDescription.pointee.mBytesPerFrame))
        return ch0Data as Data
    }
}
```

```swift
func toPCMBuffer(data: NSData) -> AVAudioPCMBuffer? {
    let audioFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 8000, channels: 1, interleaved: false)!  // given NSData audio format
    guard let PCMBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: audioFormat, frameCapacity: UInt32(data.length) / audioFormat.streamDescription.pointee.mBytesPerFrame) else {
        return nil
    }
    PCMBuffer.frameLength = PCMBuffer.frameCapacity
    let channels = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: PCMBuffer.floatChannelData, count: Int(PCMBuffer.format.channelCount))
    data.getBytes(UnsafeMutableRawPointer(channels[0]) , length: data.length)
    return PCMBuffer
}
```

Comment: Me too @Massimo.

Comment: I succeeded in transforming `NSData` in `AVAudioPCMBuffer` (I did not need the reverse, so don't have that code): http://pastebin.com/raw/m5c74FPA

Comment: @Massimo how to reverse it, means AVAudioPCMBuffer to 16 bit NSData ?

Comment: objective-c answer?

Comment: For Swift 4, replace `streamDescription.memory` with `streamDescription.pointee`.

Comment: Hi is it ok to use `.floatChannelData` when the data is actually int16?

Answer (score 14):

Copying the buffers is much easier if you copy via the audioBufferList API's. This also works no matter what the format is of the actual buffer.

```
extension Data {
    init(buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, time: AVAudioTime) {
        let audioBuffer = buffer.audioBufferList.pointee.mBuffers
        self.init(bytes: audioBuffer.mData!, count: Int(audioBuffer.mDataByteSize))
    }

    func makePCMBuffer(format: AVAudioFormat) -> AVAudioPCMBuffer? {
        let streamDesc = format.streamDescription.pointee
        let frameCapacity = UInt32(count) / streamDesc.mBytesPerFrame
        guard let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format, frameCapacity: frameCapacity) else { return nil }

        buffer.frameLength = buffer.frameCapacity
        let audioBuffer = buffer.audioBufferList.pointee.mBuffers

        withUnsafeBytes { (bufferPointer) in
            guard let addr = bufferPointer.baseAddress else { return }
            audioBuffer.mData?.copyMemory(from: addr, byteCount: Int(audioBuffer.mDataByteSize))
        }

        return buffer
    }
}
```

Comment: To avoid `'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use 'withUnsafeBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R'` warning with _Swift 5_, you can pass `addr.baseAddress` to `copyMemory` function instead of `addr`.