# UnsafeMutablePointer<Float> to UnsafeMutablePointer<_>

Tags: swift, swift3, unsafemutablepointer, avaudiopcmbuffer

I'm really going crazy with a stupid and apparently simple problem...
I have to convert a `Data` to an `AVAudioPCMBuffer`.

Looking to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048568/convert-avaudiopcmbuffer-to-nsdata-and-back) it seems to be easy, but all has changed with Swift 3. This cursed language which is continuously changing (sorry for the outburst)!

I have this snippet of code

```
let audioBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: audioFormat!, frameCapacity: UInt32(data.count)/(audioFormat?.streamDescription.pointee.mBytesPerFrame)!)
audioBuffer.frameLength = audioBuffer.frameCapacity
let channels = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: audioBuffer.floatChannelData, count: Int(audioFormat!.channelCount))
data.copyBytes(to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>(channels[0]))
```

But this last line gives me this error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>' to expected 
argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<_>'
```

May someone has a solution to this?

Comment: You might have to declare the third line as `UnsafeBufferPointer<Float>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the [API Reference of `Data`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data), you can find 3 overloads of `copyBytes`:

[`func copyBytes(to: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>, count: Int)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data/1780297-copybytes)

[`func copyBytes(to: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>, from: Range<Data.Index>)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data/1780201-copybytes)

[`func copyBytes<DestinationType>(to: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<DestinationType>, from: Range<Data.Index>?)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data/1779913-copybytes)

None of them takes `UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>` as its `to:` argument.

(And in your code, the type of `channels[0]` becomes `UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>`, passing it to an initializer of `UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>` is "do nothing".)

If you want to call the third `copyBytes`, you need to create an `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<DestinationType>`, and in your case `DestinationType` should be `Float`.

```
_ = data.copyBytes(to: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: channels[0], count: Int(audioBuffer.frameLength)))
```

(`from:` argument is optional in this `copyBytes`, and without putting `_ =`, Swift complains about not using the result.)

If you want to use other overloads of `copyBytes`, you may need to convert `UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>` to `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>`. You can find how to do that in some other articles in the SO. Please remember `count:` and `from:` (in the second) are not optional.

Comment: It works correctly, but at the end I had to manually perform the copy, because I received a [UInt8] and needed to transform it into a [Float32]... thanks!

Comment: @Massimo Can you show how you manually did the copy and converted [UInt8] to [Float32]?

Comment: @zzzel For my problem I had a Data containing n/2 samples (2 bytes for sample) and I had to transform each sample (2 bytes) in one float (between -1.0 and 1.0). If your problem is the same, this is my code (samples is a `Data`object): `for i in 0..<samples.count/2 {
            floatArray[i] = Float(Int16(samples[i*2+1]) << 8 | Int16(samples[i*2]))/Float(INT16_MAX)
        }`

Comment: @Massimo how did you figure this out? how did you knew it was [UInt8]?curious