# Converting AVAudioPCMBuffer to NSData

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, nsdata, avaudiopcmbuffer

I'm currently trying to convert the audio samples from `AVAudioPCMBuffer` to `NSData` - I had taken a look at the accepted answer on this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048568/convert-avaudiopcmbuffer-to-nsdata-and-back?noredirect=1&lq=1) and this [code from GitHub](https://github.com/tryolabs/TLSphinx/blob/master/TLSphinx/Decoder.swift) but it appears some of the `AVFAudio` API's have changed...below is the extension I have for `AVAudioPCMBuffer`:

```
private extension AVAudioPCMBuffer {

    func toNSData() -> NSData {
        let channels = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: int16ChannelData, count: 1)
        let ch0Data = NSData(bytes: channels[0], length:Int(frameCapacity * format.streamDescription.inTotalBitsPerChannel))

        return ch0Data
    }

}
```

I'm seeing an error of `Value of type 'UnsafePointer<AudioStreamBasicDescription>' has no member 'inTotalBitsPerChannel'`. So far, I've not been able to find out any other way to find out the `inTotalBitsPerChannel` value...any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any method named `inTotalBitsPerChannel` in either of the code samples you linked to; instead, they both seem to use `mBytesPerFrame`. You will also need `.pointee` to dereference the pointer. Finally, in modern Swift, you should generally prefer to use `Data` over `NSData`. So, basically, I think your extension should work if you rewrite the last line to:

```
let ch0Data = Data(bytes: channels[0], count: Int(frameCapacity * format.streamDescription.pointee.mBytesPerFrame))
```