# How to convert AVAudioPCMBuffer to NSData in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avfoundation, avaudioengine

As the title suggests.

There is an old solution in Swift [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048568/convert-avaudiopcmbuffer-to-nsdata-and-back). But I have hard time converting to Objective-C. Seems there is no Objective-C equivalent of `UnsafeBufferPointer`

Answer (score 5):

Objective-C has unsafe pointers built right into the language, so the conversion simply becomes:

```
- (NSData *)bufferToNSData:(AVAudioPCMBuffer *)buffer {
    return [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:buffer.floatChannelData[0] length:buffer.frameLength * 4];
}
```

N.B. this assumes mono 32 bit float data in the buffer. More work needs to be done to serialize all supported `AVAudioPCMBuffer` formats to `NSData`.

Comment: I need mono 16 bit data. So I assume I should use `int16ChannelData` instead of `floatChannelData`. But what is the criteria of the `4` in `buffer.frameLength * 4`. Size of float?

Comment: That’s right, and the 4 would become 2. You can dig that number out of the buffer if you want.

Comment: @LordHari did you solve the mystery. If yes please share me the code, since I am not able to get 'int16ChannelData'